# LinearLayout Add multiple items

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin

I faced a strange problem : I can't add more than one object dynamically on a LinearLayout , if they were already things , that works, So That can display multiple views

I tried with different views , there is only problems when i try to push one after the other

(there is two buttons in index 0 and 1 to test for multiple objects on the layout)

CODE :

```
    val view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.sensor_item, container, false)
    val view2 = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.nosensor_item, container, false)


    val insertPoint = viewOfLayout.findViewById(R.id.box_Parent) as LinearLayout

    insertPoint.addView(view, 2)
    //insertPoint.addView(view2, 3) //works
```

This Works too :

```
    //insertPoint.addView(view, 3)
    insertPoint.addView(view2, 2) //works
```

This doesn't works :

```
    insertPoint.addView(view, 2)
    insertPoint.addView(view2, 3) //doesn't works
```

Full Code (fragments.kt):

```
package com.corrupted.radheat.TEMPER

 import android.os.Bundle
 import android.support.v4.app.Fragment
 import android.view.LayoutInflater
 import android.view.View
 import android.view.ViewGroup
 import android.widget.*

 import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.sensor_item.view.*

 class EditFragment : Fragment() {
     lateinit var option : Spinner
     lateinit var result : TextView


     private lateinit var viewOfLayout: View
     override fun onCreateView(
             inflater: LayoutInflater,
             container: ViewGroup?,
             savedInstanceState: Bundle?


     ): View? {

         viewOfLayout =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.edit_fragment, container, false)



         //create a view to inflate the layout_item (the xml with the textView created before)
         val view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.sensor_item, container, false)
         val view2 = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.nosensor_item, container, false)


         val insertPoint = viewOfLayout.findViewById(R.id.box_Parent) as LinearLayout

         insertPoint.addView(view, 2)
         insertPoint.addView(view2, 3)

         option = view.spinner as Spinner
         result = view.textView7 as TextView
         val options = arrayOf("A","V")

         option.adapter = ArrayAdapter<String>(activity,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,options)

         option.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener{
             override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?) {
            result.text = "0"
             }

             override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?, view: View?, position: Int, id: Long) {

                 result.text = options[position]
             }
         }
     return viewOfLayout
     }



 class InfoFragment : Fragment() {

     override fun onCreateView(
             inflater: LayoutInflater,
             container: ViewGroup?,
             savedInstanceState: Bundle?
     ): View {
         // Inflate the layout for this fragment
         return inflater.inflate(R.layout.info_fragment, container, false)
     }
 }
 class ParamsFragment : Fragment() {

     override fun onCreateView(
             inflater: LayoutInflater,
             container: ViewGroup?,
             savedInstanceState: Bundle?
     ): View {
         // Inflate the layout for this fragment
         return inflater.inflate(R.layout.parameters_fragment, container,                false)
     }
     }
```

Code of the fragment :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/box_Parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Code of the added view :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:fillViewport="true"
android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
android:background="@color/background_Item_light"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView9"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="24dp"
    android:text=".0 C°"
    android:textColor="@color/Text_Color_Light"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/textView8"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView8"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textView8"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.625" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView7"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="24dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
    android:text=".0 C°"
    android:textColor="@color/Text_Color_Light"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/textView5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView5"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textView5"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.79" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView8"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="56dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:text="00"
    android:textColor="@color/Text_Color_Light"
    android:textSize="36sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageButton"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.937" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:text="@string/ROOMtext"
    android:textColor="@color/Text_Color_Light"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner"
    android:layout_width="45dp"
    android:layout_height="43dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:background="@color/UI_ITEM_OVERLAP_LIGHT"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="36dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.4"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_keyboard_arrow_up_black_24dp" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="36dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.4"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageButton"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_keyboard_arrow_down_black_24dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:text="00"
    android:textColor="@color/Text_Color_Light"
    android:textSize="36sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.652" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

MainActivity.kt :

```
package com.corrupted.radheat.TEMPER


import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment


import android.widget.*



class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

private val fragmentManager = supportFragmentManager
private val fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction()

private val editfragment = EditFragment()
private val infofragment = InfoFragment()
private val parametersfragment = ParamsFragment()




private fun showFragment(fragment: Fragment) {
    val fragmentManager = supportFragmentManager
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment)
            .commit()
}
private val mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener = BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener { item ->
    when (item.itemId) {
        R.id.action_edit -> {
            showFragment(editfragment)
            return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
        }
        R.id.action_info-> {
            showFragment(infofragment)
            return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
        }
        R.id.action_Settings-> {
            showFragment(parametersfragment)
            return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
        }
    }
    false
}


override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)



    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, infofragment)
    fragmentTransaction.commit()

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)



    val navigation = findViewById<BottomNavigationView>(R.id.activity_main_bottom_navigation)
    navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener)

    // Create a GLSurfaceView instance and set it
    // as the ContentView for this Activity.

}




}
```

Pic of it working : https://i.stack.imgur.com/MrYe1.jpg

Thanks

Comment: If I'm following you correctly, it sounds like `sensor_item` has `match_parent` for the dimension corresponding to the `LinearLayout`'s `orientation`. That is, for example, if your `LinearLayout` is `vertical`, it seems that `sensor_item`'s `layout_height` is `match_parent`. If so, then it takes up the remaining space in the `LinearLayout`, and `nosensor_item` is being pushed out the bottom, off-screen.

Comment: If it's pushed out of the `LinearLayout`'s bounds, you won't see it at all. That's what I meant by "off-screen", though that's probably not the best way to phrase that.

Comment: it's in a scrollview , event if it's off-screen i should be able to see someting ?
do you have any suggestions on what should I do

Comment: I'd rather not continue to speculate on possible issues. If you'd like a specific answer, please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue, including all relevant layouts, in the question itself. Please don't link to your code off-site.

Comment: Oh ok ... but i cant' include images

Comment: are you sure the orientation of the linearlayout you are adding views to is set to `vertical`? looks like it is set to default which is `horizontal`.

Comment: The code and layouts are the important things, and those should be posted as text. If you'd like to include a screenshot to better illustrate your description, then you can upload one or two here, I believe, but they will just show as links, which is fine.

Comment: That's the first thing i did before posting this ...

Comment: Change the `layout_height` on the outermost `<ConstraintLayout>` in the added layout to `wrap_content`. You've got a redundant `<ConstraintLayout>` there, btw. You really only need one of those.

Comment: oh that's working

Comment: I also changed android:layout_width="0dp" to match_parent